# Moving objects in a two Dimensional Array

Tags: java

I'm making a project on a [L_Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_game), now i'm stuck on the move method where my code is:

```
public void move(int row, int col) {
        char [][] temp= new char [cells.length][]; 
        for (int i= 0; i< cells.length; i++) {
            int destRow = (i+row)%cells.length;
            temp[destRow] = new char [cells[i].length];
            for (int j= 0; j < cells[i].length; j++)
                temp[destRow][(j+col)%cells[i].length] = cells[i][j];
            }
              cells= temp;
        }
```

My move method doesn't seem to be moving the objects correctly..

So output is suppose to be like the left side, the right side is the output from my code. I know i'm obviously not moving it correctly but i don't know what i'm doing wrong either...

```
    $ slide.move(0,2)                             $ slide.move(0,2)
    $ slide.cells -> {                            $ slide.cells -> {
    { , ,o, },                                 |  { , , , },
    { , ,o, },                                 |  { , , ,o},
    { , ,o,o},                                 |  { , , ,o},
    { , , , }                                  |  {o, , ,o}
    }                                             }
    $ slide.move(1,2)                             $ slide.move(1,2)
    $ slide.cells -> {                            $ slide.cells -> {
                                                > { ,o,o, },
    { , , , },                                    { , , , },
    { , ,o, },                                 |  { ,o, , },
    { , ,o, },                                 |  { ,o, , }
    { , ,o,o}                                  <
    }                                             }
```

- The '|' symbol identifies lines that are different.
- The '<' symbol points to lines in the left column that are not in the right column.
- The '>' symbol points to lines in the right column that are not in the left column.

Any idea on how i can fix my move method to get it to move correctly?

Thanks

Comment: What arguments in `.move(1,2)` mean?

Comment: @pshemo, the row and col?

Comment: @tbodt, link added to it. Short wiki page.

Comment: `row` and `col` of what? Is it vector you want to use while moving your L shape? Or is it place you want to move some piece of `L` shape? If so which piece? Is it top-left piece? You need to be more precise what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Pshemo, ah yes thats why i'm not too quite sure either. The instructions on this isn't very clear (University Assignment Task) But i believe it is your 2nd suggestions where i want to move and based on  the top-left piece "o".

Comment: Then you can split your problem in two parts. First create method that will take vector which should be used to move your `L`. Then create method that would find position of current top-left `o` (iterate over each rows and columns until you find `o`), then simply calculate vector from that position to destination position and use it with method that accepts vector.

Comment: Would you be able to help me start off for finding the position of the current top-left o? I'm kind of stuck. Am i suppose to use a for loop?

Comment: Can you describe what `move` is supposed to do? Since we don't know the initial state we can't really tell how your first output is incorrect. However, your second output appears to be doing exactly what (we guess) it is supposed to do; you do `move(1,2)` and your second output is indeed the L moved down 1 row, right 2 columns, wrapped around. It *looks* like it is doing the right thing.

Comment: What everyone has described has been correct it is based on the top left 'o' and then moved to wherever its been told. The top row should be 0, second row is 1, third row is 2, fourth row is 3. So my second output is on row 3 (2,1) instead of (1,2). I've looked at your added answer so i will see if i'm able to think of something that works correctly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "move" might not be the best name for your method. It may help organize your thoughts if you give it a name that more closely reflects the intention, like "moveTo" or "placeLAt" or "setPosition", etc.

Comment: @JasonC Thanks heaps for your help the last couple days. You've been really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off of grexter89's answer, presuming that `move(r,c)` is supposed to place L at that position (rather than move the L by the specified amount -- correct me if I'm wrong):

Your program is behaving exactly as you told it to behave:

- Move current state, storing the result in a new temporary state.
- Set current state to the new moved state.

Your moves are incremental, because that's the program you wrote. For these types of things, think of it like a "translation": Express what you want to do in English (or whatever) then *translate* it to your code. If the above two steps aren't what you want to do, then you started off with the wrong idea.

It seems like what you *really* want to do is this. First you define an initial state where the L is in the top left corner, and when you start you set the current state to that initial state. Then move does this:

- Move initial state, storing the result in a new temporary state.
- Set current state to new moved state.

See the difference? With the above steps, every move starts at the *initial* state instead of incrementally being applied to the *current* state.

Of course, you could simplify the above a bit (you don't need a temporary state, really) but I'm trying to keep the example straightforward.

Your code is fundamentally correct in that it *does* move a grid correctly, you're just not applying it to the grid (current state) that you intended to apply it to (initial state).

Hopefully that is enough to get you going here.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're moving the L relative to its last position, but in your left example `row` and `col` specify the absolute position of the top 'o'.